# search by product id

Tags: magento-1.8, search

If we want to search by name or sku, we can just alter the their respective attribute settings in admin panel. But how to search by mentioning product id?

I thought changing `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Search_Catalog` would does the same but I figured it out that it doesn't.

```
    $collection = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getSearchCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id') /* added */
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
        ->addSearchFilter($this->getQuery())
        ->setCurPage($this->getStart())
        ->setPageSize($this->getLimit())
        ->load();
```

Please help.

Comment: Later, I realized searching by product id is not possible in magento. even though if we get a way to do it, we end up writing a big code.. better move to other attributes which are similar to product ids.

Comment: How we can get it  done on Magento 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Search_Collection` resource model.

Particularly the `_getSearchEntityIdsSql` function

I'm not yet sure how to add your code here, I'll search and update my post, except if one expert can help you replacing this resource model.

Edit. Apparently there is a foreach on each searchable attribute that append the results in a  `$selects[]` array.

Try adding your request in the `$selects` array just after the end of foreach.

Comment: Sir, I am not good with sql, php and even magento.. if you just guide me with some code that will be better for me. I hope you have time for that :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to search by id:

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $ids));
```

Comment: Sohil, where should I add this code? I tried in my above shown code, still it doesn't search by id...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$product_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => $searchstring))
    ->load();
```

Comment: Su123, Where should I add this code? I tried in my above shown code, still it doesn't search by id...

Comment: what is `$searchstring` here?

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't mention. It is the product id which you enter for search

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Magento 2:**

Need to override a function in file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/ResourceModel/Search/Collection.php
```

Function name is:
**`protected function _getSearchEntityIdsSql($query, $searchOnlyInCurrentStore = true)`**

**Just update the foreach loop as below:**

```
foreach ($this->_getAttributesCollection() as $attribute) {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Entity\Attribute $attribute */
            $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            if ($this->_isAttributeTextAndSearchable($attribute)) {
                $table = $attribute->getBackendTable();
                if (!isset($tables[$table]) && $attribute->getBackendType() != 'static') {
                    $tables[$table] = [];
                }
        
                if ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'static') {
                    // This condition handles attributes stored directly in the main entity table
                    $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
                        $table,
                        $linkField
                    )->where(
                        $this->_resourceHelper->getCILike($attributeCode, $this->_searchQuery, $likeOptions)
                    );
                    // Add the select to the $selects array
                    $selects[] = $select;
        
                    // Now, also include 'entity_id' as a separate search attribute
                    $selects[] = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
                        $table,
                        $linkField
                    )->where(
                        $this->_resourceHelper->getCILike('entity_id', $this->_searchQuery, $likeOptions)
                    );
                } else {
                    // For non-static attributes, store them for processing later
                    $tables[$table][] = $attribute->getId();
                }
            }
        }
```

This will make product id searchable in `Search By Keyword`.